# User events in unix c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix

I am trying to port my multi threaded windows application to Unix. In my application, we have user created events which signals the thread to perform specific task.I found that the conditional variable or semaphore can be used to signal threads.My requirement is to create dynamic events on request but that is not feasible with conditional variable or semaphore.Help me to use the events like signalling concepts in Unix.

Comment: I don't see why "that is not feasible with conditional variable or semaphore".

Comment: I am creating some set of events and storing the event handle in queue.Threads will take the events from the queue and use the event to signal other threads. Here one thread will wait for multiple signals(in windows, WaitForMultipleObjects) but this is not feasible with conditional variables. they won't listen for multiple signals.

Comment: If you insist in "Event" as in Windows, of course it's not feasible for Unix as it doesn't even exist in Unix. But if what you want is something can achieve same goal as `WaitForMultipleObjects` does, there are so many way to do. i.e. you can change you "event set" into a semaphore or a concurrent queue, and tell all worker threads to wait for it.

Comment: Its not multiple threads,its single thread waiting for multiple events to set and once set the thread will perform defined task.

Answer (score 0):

Posix threads allow you to communicate between threads with mutex and conditions. `man pthreads`, `man pthread_cond_wait` and other.

Another way to make events doesn't depend on threads and made on descriptors.
See `man epoll`, `man poll`, `man select`

Implementing event system manually in `C` may take some time, so there are libraries, that are implementing event system like `libev`, `libuv`, `libevent`, `libevent2`.

If you want more `C++` then `C` you can use `boost` (like `boost::signals`. Don't know if there are other) or `Qt`, which has full signal/slot mechanism and event system built in. But it requires quite heavy dependencies.

If you want full implemented event queue and many interprise features you can look at any `AMQP` framework like `rabbitmq`.

It's hard to tell you what you need without specific problems.

Comment: I have a thread which will wait for multiple events to set.                                                                                                                        WaitForMultipleObjects(8,lup_ReleaseParam->msp_AcquizationEvent, FALSE,1). In Unix I didn't found equivalent wait methods for multiple event  signal. If i am using conditional variable "pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex)" , this won't listen for multiple events.Guide me to sort it out

Comment: @vanith55 Did you read about the other possibilities I mentioned? I'm not familiar with Windows programming, but according to msdn and your FALSE parameter you want to handle the event as it happened (you don't wait all). So you can use one of "poll" "select" or "epoll" to do this. You can create a pipe (see man pipe) or socketpair (see man socketpair) and use write descriptor in a thread to signal that the thread finished the task and set all read descriptors to event function (poll, epoll, select)  in your main thread to get the event. But I highly suggest to use libraries I wrote in post.